# Can you depreciate assets differently between Federal, State, and Local?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, business

I want to claim a Federal Section 179 deduction for some assets. Write off the entire amount in the year I bought it. However, with Pennsylvania State Tax Laws, it makes more sense to spread the cost of those assets over 5 years.

So federal would see the assets depreciated immediately.
State would see it depreciated over 5 years. Same thing with local.
Is it legal to do this?

The reason why I want to do this is because I will get a larger tax return from doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you most definitely can. In some cases you must.

However for each State you'll have to check whether you can *choose* how to depreciate. Many States require you to take the same depreciation as on the Federal schedule, including Sec. 179, others won't allow Sec. 179 at all.

Specifically to PA, I haven't found any current guidance, but [the rules from 2012 put PA](http://www.revenue.pa.gov/GeneralTaxInformation/TaxLawPoliciesBulletinsNotices/Documents/Informational%20Notices/info_notice_pit_2012-05.pdf) in the bucket that **requires** you to take the same Sec. 179 on the State return as appears on your Federal return.

> If you elect to expense Section 179 Property for FIT purposes, you are
>   required to expense the property for PIT purposes.

However PA limit for Sec. 179 is $25K, so if your Federal deduction is larger - you can depreciate the rest.

Check with a PA-licensed CPA or EA for a more reliable opinion, since I'm not a tax adviser. Just googled it.